# Add Imports to Imports Table, is it Possible?

Tags: exe, portable-executable, import

I'm coding in C, and I want to know if it's possible to Add Imports to Any Compiled EXE from an already Imported library, for example, the EXE Imports

> Kernel32.dll
>      GetFileSize(), FindNextFileA, FindFirstFileA

Is there any method I can add another function to this list? Let's say `CreateMutexA` for example?

Comment: Why would you want to add an import?

Answer (score 0):

Putting Items in the so called "Import Table" is the job of the compiler (the Linker) when it detects that an application being compiled is statically linked to a library because it uses a specific function. In your example, the application you would compile invokes the CreateMutexA API and would be then statically linked to Kernel32.lib. When the loader will start your application, it would detect that your application has been statically linked to Kernel32.lib because of the presence of FindNextFile in the Import Table and the name of the library (kernel32.dll) in the Import Table and would then search for the presence of Kernel32.dll, which of course always present already loaded in memory). The presence of an item in the Import Table, means that the API will be invoked (soon or later). The absence of an item in the Import Table, means that the API won't be invoked (unless, you use LoadLibrary and GetProcAdress - aka using runtime Dynamic Link Library!)

NO, there is no specific API one can invoke to "artificially" add an item into the Import Table. You could, in theory, do this - if you speak PE - directly by modifying (fooling) the image, but this is another story, since you would need to adjust the size of the modified PE section that contains the Import Table!